# Android Studio Rendering Problems, classes could not be found for custom TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am running into rendering issues and have not figured out how to resolve. I created a custom textview class that will set the view to a custom typeface. I believe my setup is correct, but for some reason the custom text is not being applied and I am receiving rendering issues in my layouts that are using this custom textview widget. Here is my setup.

Custom TextView Class

```
public class FontedTextView extends TextView {

    public FontedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FontedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
    }

    public FontedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        CustomFontHelper.setCustomFont(this, context, attrs);
    }
}
```

Helper class to set the typeface

```
class CustomFontHelper {

    public static void setCustomFont(TextView textview, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomFont);
        String font = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomFont_font);
        setCustomFont(textview, font, context);
        a.recycle();
    }

    private static void setCustomFont(TextView textview, String font, Context context) {
         if (font == null) {
            return;
        }

        Typeface tf = FontCache.get(font, context);
        if (tf != null) {
            textview.setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

I use the textView like this in my layouts

```
        <com.example.gui.FontedTextView
            style="@style/CustomTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test new text typeface"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
```

In styles.xml, I added a style that references my custom font

```
<style name="CustomTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="com.example:font">fonts/UglyFont.otf</item>
</style>
```

My attrs.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomFont">
        <attr name="font" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

This is an issue I have found in other threads but my particular case seems a little different. I am not referencing AppCompact in my styles, so I do not need to add any support libraries or dependencies. There are conflicts specifically with the custom textView I created. Here is what the error says.

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>
> - com.example.gui.FontedTextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>
> Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show
>   sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/gui/CustomFontHelper
>     at com.example.gui.FontedButton.(FontedButton.java:19)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)

Things I have tried but the issue was not resolved

--Invalidate cache and restart

--Rebuild / Clean

--Change SDK level from 23 to 21, 20, 19, 18, and 17. Didn't make a difference

Comment: It looks like compiler can't found CustomHelper CustomFontHelper.

Comment: replace "com.example:font" with "font" in style.xml

Comment: @WaleedSarwar I did as you said, the typeface still does not change. And I am uncertain why CustomFontHelper cannot be found. The classes, FontedTextView and CustomFontHelper are in the same package. I refactored CustomFontHelper to see if the reference changed in FontedTextView and it did. Any other suggestions?

Comment: i think its a IDE problem.Are you are using latest version of android Studio.Because i have tried your code it worked for me

Comment: Yea, even later because I am on the dev channel. Using 1.4 RC2. but I have this issue on 1.3 as well. I do not think this is IDE issue because the font I want to be applied is not being applied.